# MVC4: Modelstate is not valid when creating a new record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, record, modelstate

I try to add a new Country which has a link to continent. When I press the "Create" button, it doesn't add a new record. I debugged my project and I think it's because the ValidState is false. The reason because of this is that the property "Continent" is null, but the Continent_Id isn't. 
I have the same problem when I try to edit an existing Country. (I have populated my database with an SQL script in SQL Management Studio)

Can someone help me please?

**Continent class:**

```
public class Continent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public virtual List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

**Country class**

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public int Continent_Id { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    [Required, ForeignKey("Continent_Id")]
    public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller class ( create function )**

```
  //
    // GET: /Countries/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Continent_Id = new SelectList(db.Continents, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Countries/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Country country)
    {
       var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors); //to check the errors
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Countries.Add(country);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        ViewBag.Continent_Id = new SelectList(db.Continents, "Id", "Name", country.Continent_Id);
        return View(country);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by putting the Required validation off of Continent, and set it only at the Continent_Id. Now the ID property is required, but the Continent isn't.

```
public class Country
{
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required, MaxLength(25)]
public string Name { get; set; }
[MaxLength(5)]
public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

[Required] //added Required
public int Continent_Id { get; set; }

//Navigation
[ForeignKey("Continent_Id")] //removed Required
public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for the responses !

Answer (score 4):

Just before the line **if (ModelState.IsValid)** put this
ModelState.Remove("v_id"); 
Where v_id is your primarykey column name in your case

Comment: this works for me, i have no idea why for a new record, validation run for ID field.

Comment: I had the same problem, modelstate was not valid even though id=0. Your solution worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I believe your issue is timing.  Model validation happens automatically during binding; at that time, the Continent property is null.  You set the property later but the model state is not re-evaluated when you check IsValid.  I see three options:

- Quick and dirty: Take the Required validation off of Continent and validate Continent_Id instead, adding a check in the controller to ensure a valid Continent is retrieved from Find().
- Most work: Create a custom model binder to actually use the Continent_Id to retrieve and populate the Continent.  You are almost there on this one since having both Continent_Id and Continent as properties of Country is redundant and an opportunity for inconsistencies.
- Probably best option: Make your controller accept a view model that only has the data you expect to come back from the form and populate a Country object from it.

Comment: Can you pleaes give a little more information for option 3 (the best option).

Comment: I think @Jan has option 3 covered.  Essentially, you should let each layer of the application deal with a model that makes sense for them.  So your domain model is Country, which has all the fields you need for data storage, etc.  But in the web layer, your form doesn't have all that information so you create a CountryViewModel that makes sense for the data you do have and translate between the two as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the ModelState isn't valid is because you have marked the Continent property as required but in i guess in your view you don't have form fields the will bind to some properties of the Continent object.

So either don't mark the Continent object as required or provide a hidden field with a name of Continent.Id or Continent.Name so that the model binder will populate the Continent property:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Continent.Id)
```

But that will lead to the next problem: You habe marked the Name property of the Continent class as required so you will have to provide a form field for that property too.

The base problem is, that you try to reuse your repository classes as viewmodel classes.
A better approach would be to use separate classes as viewmodels to pass your data between the controller and the view:

```
class CountryViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public int Continent_Id { get; set; }
}
```

To map between your Country and CountryViewModel object use a mapper like AutoMapper.

Comment: In my views I have a dropdownlist with the Continents. When I select the continent name, the Continent_Id will be filled in. But I have a property Continent_Id (which is filled in correctly) and a Continent property, which is empty..

Comment: Yes, thats what i wrote. The Continent property is null, because i guess that you don't have any form field in your view which posts a value to some property of th Continent class. No property of your Continent class is called Continent_Id!